# Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - error creating media/catalog/product

Tags: magento, magmi, image-upload

I'm using `Magmi` to bulk upload products including images. The products upload fine, but i get the error message when `magmi` tries to upload the images:-

```
plugin;
ImageAttributeItemProcessor;
```

> warning:Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - error creating media/catalog/product/1/0: 2,mkdir(): Permission denied

I have set the Dir & File permissions to 777
the filesystem path to `magento` directory is set to ../..

Any ideas anyone?
thanks

Comment: Please post your code so people can check it.

Comment: hi, there is no code the upload is done via a flat .csv file.

Comment: I too have this issue

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing the following:

In {magmi-dir}/plugins/extra/itemprocessors/imageprocessor/imageitattributeemprocessor.php class ImageAttributeItemProcessor in method copyImageFile() there is a line that has $l2d="media/catalog/product/$i1/$i2";

I had to change that media path to be the absolute path, so for me that line became $l2d="/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/$i1/$i2";